# How we can drag element from one frame and drop to another frame in selenium web driver with python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, frame

How we can drag element from one frame and drop to another frame in selenium webdriver with python?

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example, or at least confirm the url and your code attempts until now?

Comment: will below cover work?                                                                                         driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/driver/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html?overview-summary.html")
driver.switch_to.frame("packageFrame")
ele = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "AbstractAnnotations")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.click_and_hold(ele)
driver.switch_to.default_content()
frm = driver.switch_to.frame("classFrame")
action.drag_and_drop(ele, frm).perform()

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.